# Why GitLab shows a failure badge in green for failed Jenkins builds?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, badge

I just configured CI integration for GitLab merge requests between Jenkins and GitLab. I have GitLab Community Edition 11 which doesn't provide Jenkins integration (Enterprise Edition has it), so I had to do the most on the Jenkins side using GitLab plugin for Jenkins.

So I did the first test with both successful and failed builds (`exit 1` in my Freestyle script). Everything seemed to work fine, except that I was surprised to see that the failure X badge in GitLab has green background!

**Why so? How do I make it red for failed builds?**

[image: GitLab build icons for Jenkins]

Comment: That looks like a bug to me - I can't believe that's deliberate, or configurable. If you check the CSS classes on the success and failure icons do they look sensible, i.e there's nothing in the failure case that also says success? Can you track down the CSS where the green is coming from? But ultimately this might be something you'll have to report to GitLab directly.

Comment: @Rup I found they are using Unicode emoji icons, and specifically this one for failed builds: https://emojipedia.org/negative-squared-cross-mark/   Yes, I suspected it might be a bug but I thought maybe it somehow reacts to the exit code and gets red for "more serious errors". I'll try to look through GitLab issue tracker to see if somebody has reported it or if it has been fixed in some update (but unfortunately I cannot update it soon).